# How can I update the External Data Source via Metadata Api or Tooling Api?

Tags: metadata-api, tooling-api, sandbox-refresh, lightning-connect, education-data-architecture

I have a record for External Data Source Named as **ED1** which is password protected having below details.

```
DeveloperName   ED1
Endpoint        abc.com
IsDeleted       FALSE
IsWritable      FALSE
MasterLabel     ED1
PrincipalType   NamedUser
Protocol        Password
Type            OData
```

I need to write a script which will make Endpoint as null whenever I do a sandbox refresh. How can I achieve it?
I tasted with below code and getting Error as *' Unresolved data provider Apex class reference: '*

```
global static void externalDataSource(){
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
        
        MetadataService.ExternalDataSource externalDataSource = new MetadataService.ExternalDataSource();
        externalDataSource.fullName = 'ED1';
        externalDataSource.endpoint = null;
        externalDataSource.principalType = 'NamedUser';
        externalDataSource.Protocol = 'Password';
        
        MetadataService.SaveResult[] results = service.updateMetadata(
            new List<MetadataService.Metadata>{ externalDataSource }
        );
        
        for (MetadataService.SaveResult result : results) {
            if (result.success) {
                //Success
                System.debug(result);
            } else {
                //Failed
                System.debug(result.errors[0].message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added the extra parameters to make it work as below.
These are some of the required fields needed in Metadata API as well as in Tooling API.

```
MetadataService.ExternalDataSource externalDataSource = new MetadataService.ExternalDataSource();
externalDataSource.fullName = 'ED1';
externalDataSource.endpoint = 'dumyURL';
externalDataSource.label = 'ED1';
externalDataSource.principalType = 'NamedUser';
externalDataSource.Protocol = 'Password';
externalDataSource.type_x = 'OData';
externalDataSource.username = 'sfdcodatauser';
```